# Fixed div at bottom of the window then stays above the footer when the page is scrolled down

Tags: jquery, html, css, footer, sticky

I would like a sticky bar to stay at the bottom of the window at all times. As the user scrolls down to the bottom of the page the same bar will stay fixed until the footer shows, then removes its fixed position, temporarily, to stay above the footer until the user scrolls back up and it remains fixed again.

I've achieved a similar effect with a navigation bar (calculated from the top of the window) on another project, but can't figure out reverse it as scrollBottom doesn't seem to exist.

This is the working header code:

```
var nav = $('.nav');
    fixed = 'nav-fixed';
    hh = $('header').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > hh ) {
        nav.addClass(fixed);
    } else {
        nav.removeClass(fixed);
    }
});
```

When the trigger class is called:

```
.fixed {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10
    bottom: 0;
}
```

How would I reverse it for the footer?

Many thanks, Jack.

Comment: Seeing your CSS would be useful as well.

Comment: Well, isn't scrollBottom just scrollTop + height?

Comment: Is that how it works? this is pretty new to me

Comment: Would that be scrollTop + height - footer height? It's the logic that I'm struggling with

Comment: Don't worry, think I have found it http://jsfiddle.net/PBn8q/5/ - I'll post an answer when I have adapted this.

Comment: Not so much "how it works" as "logical deduction" :)

Comment: I have almost got it working, but I need to trigger it after a certain page width, I have posted the updated code and example on this new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985099/a-cleaner-way-for-a-fixed-div-at-bottom-of-the-window-but-stays-above-the-footer